# How to create a docker container that intentionally goes in CrashLoopBackOff?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubectl

I want to test a  logging and recovery scenario in which alert is generated and test system response in loopback crash for which i need a docker image that crashes after deployment

Comment: You don't need to build an image for this, just use image like `ubuntu` OR `bash` So pod will start and execute the command and exit. Leading to crashlookbackoff. Eg, `k run foo --image ubuntu` . M

Answer (score 0):

Used the following Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:8

RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*


RUN yum install -y gdb

RUN yum group install -y "Development Tools"

CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]
```

and for .yaml file for kubernetes created a docker image and pushed it to dockerhub

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: crashme
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: crashme
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: crashme
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: crashme
        image: harshityadav95/crashme:firsttry
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1024Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1024Mi
```